# accidentely deleted etc folder now geting error PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: amazon-ec2, magento2, amazon-rds

Hi my website was working fine accidentally I deleted etc folder I had env.php file which i restored  but I have new config.php ,di.xml and rest of the other file in etc folder
Also
I customize theme with configurable product ,catergory plugin (category on front page)
with the help of one developer now I can't get hold of him
any help would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

In shell please run the following commands:

```
rm -rf generated

rm -rf var/*
```

PS. Are the uploaded files of the same Magento version?